# Issue using images in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I am creating a Blackjack GUI game with Tkinter and I'm running into an issue where the deal button clears the image of the old card from the screen when a new one is added. My educated guess is the `card_image` inside the `deal()` function is overwriting itself when I use the function again. If this is the case why is this and what's the best fix? Thanks.

```
import random
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root =Tk()
root.title('21 Blackjack')
root.iconbitmap('images/21_cards.ico')
root.geometry('1280x750')
root.configure(bg='green')

cards = []

suits = ['hearts', 'clubs', 'diamonds', 'spades']
face_cards = ['ace', 'jack', 'queen', 'king']

extension = 'png'

for y in suits:
    for x in range(2, 11):
        name = 'images/{}-{}.{}'.format(str(x), y, extension)
        cards.append(name)

    for x in face_cards:
        name = 'images/{}-{}.{}'.format(str(x), y, extension)
        cards.append(name)

print(cards)
print(len(cards))
random.shuffle(cards)
print(cards[0])

hand = []

def deal():
    global card_image, card_label, hand
    card_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(cards[0]).resize((180, 245), Image.ANTIALIAS))
    card_label = Label(root, image=card_image, relief="raised").pack(side="left")
    hand += cards[:1]
    cards.pop(0)
    print(hand)

deal_button = Button(root, text="deal", command=deal).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try `cards.pop()` instead of `cards.pop(0)` ?

Comment: No good. The same issue only now it adds the same card instead of a new one.

Comment: Try using ```card_image``` and ```card_label``` as local variables instead of using ithem globally. That way a new card will be created each time

Comment: That makes sense however without making them global no images appear at all.

Comment: Remove the global and say `card_label.image = card_image`, so in that there is a reference to the image kept.

Comment: Is this as a new line under ```card_label = Label```? If so same issue still.

Comment: This suggestion was based of what Lcj said.

Comment: I mean when I remove ```card_image``` and ```card_label``` globals and put ```card_label.image = card_image``` I get the same issue. Unless I'm implementing that change wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an image pool. Lucky for you, I have one right here

```
import os
from glob import glob
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from typing import List, Tuple, Union, Dict, Type
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Image_dc:
    image  :Image.Image
    rotate :int                = 0
    photo  :ImageTk.PhotoImage = None
    
    def size(self) -> Tuple[int]:
        if not self.photo is None:
            return self.photo.width(), self.photo.height()
            
        return self.image.width, self.image.height


class ImagePool(object):
    ##__> PRIVATE INTERFACE <__##
    
    __PATHS  = dict()
    __IMAGES = dict()
    
    @staticmethod
    def __name(path) -> str:
        return os.path.basename(os.path.splitext(path)[0])
            
    @staticmethod
    def __unique(path:str, prefix:str='') -> str:
        name = f'{prefix}{ImagePool.__name(path)}'
        if name in ImagePool.names():
            sol = 'using a prefix' if not prefix else f'changing your prefix ({prefix})'
            msg = ("WARNING:\n"
                  f"{name} was not loaded due to a same-name conflict.\n"
                  f"You may want to consider {sol}.\n\n")
            print(msg)
                   
            return None
            
        return name
            
    @staticmethod
    def __request(name:str) -> Image_dc:
        if name in ImagePool.__PATHS:
            path = ImagePool.paths(name)
            if os.path.isfile(path):
                if name not in ImagePool.__IMAGES:   
                    ImagePool.__IMAGES[name] = Image_dc(Image.open(path))
                return ImagePool.__IMAGES[name]
            else:
                raise ValueError(f'ImagePool::__request - Path Error:\n\tpath is not a valid file\n\t{path}')
                
        raise NameError(f'ImagePool::__request - Name Error:\n\t"{name}" does not exist')
        return None
    
    @staticmethod
    def __size(iw:int, ih:int, w:int=None, h:int=None, scale:float=1.0) -> Tuple[int]:
        if not w is None and not h is None:
            if iw>ih:
                ih = ih*(w/iw)
                r = h/ih if (ih/h) > 1 else 1
                iw, ih = w*r, ih*r
            else:
                iw = iw*(h/ih)
                r = w/iw if (iw/w) > 1 else 1
                iw, ih = iw*r, h*r
                
        return int(iw*scale), int(ih*scale)
        
    ##__> PUBLIC INTERFACE <__##
    
    @staticmethod
    def names(prefix:str='') -> List[str]:
        names = [*ImagePool.__PATHS]
        return names if not prefix else list(filter(lambda name, pre=prefix: name.startswith(pre), names))
        
    @staticmethod
    def paths(name:str=None) -> Union[Dict, str]:
        if name is None:
            return ImagePool.__PATHS
            
        if name in ImagePool.__PATHS:
            return ImagePool.__PATHS[name]
            
        raise NameError(f'ImagePool::paths - Name Error:\n\tname "{name}" does not exist')
        
    @staticmethod
    def images(name:str=None, prefix:str='') -> Union[Dict, Image.Image]:
        if name is None:
            return {name:ImagePool.__request(name).image for name in self.names(prefix)}
            
        return ImagePool.__request(name).image
    
    @staticmethod
    def photos(name:str=None, prefix:str='') -> Union[Dict, ImageTk.PhotoImage]:
        if name is None:
            return {name:ImagePool.__request(name).photo for name in self.names(prefix)}
        
        return ImagePool.__request(name).photo
        
    @staticmethod
    def append_file(path:str, prefix:str='') -> Type:
        if not os.path.isfile(path):
            raise ValueError(f'ImagePool::append_file - Value Error:\n\tpath is not valid\n\t{path}')
            
        name = ImagePool.__unique(path, prefix)
        
        if name:
            ImagePool.__PATHS[name] = path
            
        return ImagePool
            
    @staticmethod
    def append_directory(directory:str, filters=['*.png', '*.jpg'], prefix:str='') -> Type:
        if not os.path.isdir(directory):
            raise ValueError(f'ImagePool::append_directory - Value Error:\n\tdirectory is not valid\n\t{directory}')
            
        filters = filters if isinstance(filters, (List, Tuple)) else [filters]
            
        for filter in filters:
            for path in glob(f'{directory}/{filter}'):
                ImagePool.append_file(path, prefix)
                
        return ImagePool
    
    @staticmethod
    def photo(name:str, width:int=None, height:int=None, scale:float=1.00, rotate:int=None) -> ImageTk.PhotoImage:
        image_t = ImagePool.__request(name)
        size    = ImagePool.__size(*image_t.size(), width, height, scale)
        rotate  = image_t.rotate if rotate is None else rotate
                    
        #only resize if the new size or rotation is different than the current photo size or rotation
        #however, a small margin for error must be considered for the size            
        diff = tuple(map(lambda i, j: i-j, image_t.size(), size)) 
        if (diff > (1, 1)) or (diff < (-1, -1)) or (image_t.rotate != rotate):
            image_t.rotate = rotate
            image_t.photo  = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_t.image.resize(size, Image.LANCZOS).rotate(rotate))
              
        return image_t.photo
```

Using that file you can do a lot of things very easily. You can put all your card images in a folder and get them all with:

```
ImagePool.append_directory(path_to_folder)
```

You can then get any card and force it to fit in it's parent  (no-matter-what) with:

```
somelabel['image'] = ImagePool.photo(image_name, allotted_width, allotted_height)
```

or just:

```
somelabel['image'] = ImagePool.photo(image_name)
```

you can get a list of every name in the pool with

```
deck = ImagePool.names()
```

or grab it while you also append a directory

```
deck = ImagePool.append_directory(path_to_folder).names()
```

That is very helpful to you, because you can simply shuffle and pop that list as the official "deck" in your game. Like this:

```
somecard['image'] = ImagePool.photo(deck.pop(0))
```

Assuming you will have more than just card graphics, but do not want to get all the images when creating a deck, there is a solution for that, as well.

first supply a prefix when appending the cards image directory, and then use that prefix when calling `names()`. As long as only card images were in the cards image directory, only card names will be returned.

```
deck = ImagePool.append_directory(path_to_folder, prefix='cards_').names('cards_')
```

notes:

`allotted` area is only allotted and in no way should be assumed to represent the final width and/or height of the actual image. The image will do whatever it has to to fit in the allotted space without losing it's original height and width ratio. If you don't supply allotted width **and** height the image will be it's full size.

All image and photo references are automatically maintained in `ImagePool`. There is no reason to store your own references

The entire class is static so references to all the images and photos can be accessed anywhere without an `ImagePool` instance. In other words, you never need to do this: `images = ImagePool()` and therefore never need to figure out how to get `images` into some `class` or other document.

No images actually load until you start requesting them, and then it happens automatically. This is a good thing. You have 52 cards, but if you only use ex: 6 in the first game ~ only 6 will fully load. Eventually all the cards will get played and be fully loaded, and you didn't have some huge burp in your game where you tried to fully create 52 cards all at once.

The `ImagePool` class has more features, but the ones explained here are all you should need for your game.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
card_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(cards[0]).resize((180, 245), Image.ANTIALIAS))
card_label = Label(root, image=card_image, relief="raised").pack(side="left")
```

Do:

```
card_label = Label(root, image=card_image, relief="raised").pack(side="left")
card_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(cards[0]).resize((180, 245), Image.ANTIALIAS))
card_label.image = card_image #Keeps reference to the image so it's not garbage collected
```

Do note when you want use the photo use the variable `card_image`

Answer (score 0):

As people have pointed out I needed to add `card_label.image = card_image` to the function and remove `card_image` & `card_label` global to stop the image being removed. But for some reason Python didn't like having the image being packed before I did this.

The function now looks like this.

```
    global hand
    card_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(cards[0]).resize((180, 245), Image.ANTIALIAS))
    card_label = Label(root, image=card_image, relief="raised")
    card_label.image = card_image
    card_label.pack(side="left")
    hand += cards[:1]
    cards.pop(0)
    print(hand)
```

Comment: You can use `hand.append(cards.pop(0))` to replace `hand += cards[:1]` and `cards.pop(0)`.